# wkhtmltopdf div background color

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the `wkhtmltopdf` on my amazon ubuntu instance to generate an invoice's PDF. The page is PHP. Everything is working fine except the background color of the html div tags. The border color is working fine. Is there any setting in `wkhtmltopdf` to enable printing background color of the div tag?

I have tried bgcolor, css and inline style, also I have checked converting the page in Table structure but none of these helped.

Comment: Is the background present in the HTML output before converting with wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: Yes, the background is there on the page.

Comment: Do you use an external css file ? And if so, is wkhtmltopdf able to load this style sheet ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had this issue as well, and the css was right in the same HTML file. The trick for me ended up being the somewhat-mysterious "!important" at the end of the background-color tag like so:

```css
background-color: #f2f4f7 !important;
```

Comment: hi snippet dose not work do you mean here remove important or add it ?

Comment: @shareef Add, not remove. If you have a div that is styled with a background color but it is not happening in the resulting PDF, try adding !important to the background color declaration and that should work. It is odd.

Comment: @DJGrossman thanks , whats seems to be my problem solved by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706302/no-display-of-image-as-a-pattern-in-svg-circle#comment86607971_34706302

Answer (score 1):

Use This especially when you generate PDF from google App Script

```
@media print 
{
.class 
{
     background-color: #1a4567 !important;
     -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can work around it by adding `!important` to the CSS rule
then you have a `@media print` rule getting in the way

for instance, in my case, the CSS rules I had included:

```
@media print {
    background: transparent !important; /* <= DISABLES backgrounds */
}
```

among many other `@media print` rules with `!important` that I wanted to remove for my PDF to get some styles of the targeted HTML

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with border color was working but with background color not.

The only thing that worked for me was to set the `background-color` directly in the `div`. For example:

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(81, 130, 187) !important;"></div>
```

Don't forget to use the `!important` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case the solution was to specify the color in rgba instead of hex. No need to specify within HTML.

```
background-color: rgba(249, 203, 156, 0.71);
```

instead of

```
background-color: #F9CB9CB5;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing this issue not solved by accepted answer - It may be possible that you specified following no-background configuration -

```
[
    'binary' => 'D:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe',
    'commandOptions' => [
        'print-media-type',
        'page-size' => 'Ledger',
        'no-background'
    ]
]
```

Remove 'no-background' config and the background color will show up.